# PowerShell issue: Invoke method "Cannot cast object of type ‘System.String’ to type ‘System.String[]’

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm currently trying to run a .NET application in PowerShell. I'm using System.Reflection.Assembly to load the bytes in memory of an assembly written in C#.

The .NET application has one method, `Main(System.String[] args)`, and it will list the values passed as argument of the function. Very simple program.

Here's the PowerShell code :

```powershell
[String] $assemblyPath = "C:\Users\HakkYahud\Desktop\HelloWorld.exe"
[String[]]$parameter_main = @( "test" )

[Byte[]]$assemblyByte = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($assemblyPath)
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($assemblyByte)
$entryPoint = $assembly.EntryPoint
$parameter_invoke = @( $parameter_main )

Write-Host $parameter_main.GetType()
Write-Host $parameter_invoke.GetType()
Write-Host $entryPoint
Write-Host @( "test", "test2" ).GetType()

$entryPoint.Invoke($null, $parameter_invoke)
```

I know that method `Invoke` takes 2 parameters `Object obj` and `Object[] parameters`.

Once running the code, an error occurs in the function Invoke, it is saying that "it cannot cast System.String to the type System.String[]"

The variable `$parameter_main` is already `System.String[]`, why does the compiler need to cast from `System.String` to `System.String[]`?

Moreover, when I'm putting `$parameter_main = @("test", "test2")`, I'm receiving another error saying "*Wrong number of arguments*"

Has anyone already encountered this issue?

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell's pipeline processor loves *enumerating* output. This means that when you use the array subexpression `@(...)` like this:

```
$innerArray = 1,2
$outerArray = @( $innerArray )
```

... PowerShell evaluates `$innerArray`, sees that it's an array, enumerates all the items in the array, and the resulting array value stored in `$outerArray` thus becomes a flat array containing the exact same items as `$innerArray`.

To prevent this array-flattening, there are two options:

- Use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` to signal that PowerShell should *not* attempt to enumerate the items from inner array:

  - `$parameter_invoke = @( Write-Output $parameter_main -NoEnumerate )`
- Wrap the inner array in another array literal-expression:

  - `$parameter_invoke = @( ,$parameter_main )`

Comment: Thank you sir ! $parameter_invoke = @( ,$parameter_main ) is working. Quite an annoying behavior that evaluate the element of the array when the entire array is passed as a argument of the function

Comment: @SkallZou It's annoying _in this particular context_ (where you need to construct a nested array), but PowerShell would be a nightmare to work with if it _didn't_ behave like this 95% of the time :)